# Express + Mongoose + Aggregation + Calculate Available Stock

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework, stock

I'm using express js and mongoose and i'm new to these platforms. It would be great if someone can help me on this. Please refer the the below data and I'm looking for output like:

```
itemsizeId: 609578ca23033e55886e7590, AvailableQuantity: 112

itemsizeId: 609578ca23033e55886e758f, AvailableQuantity: 495
```

Note: Group by **movementtype** (inward / outward).

Available Stock: inward - outward

```
[
  {
    _id: '609fb1a1a7ed990f30d6cae2',
    refId: 'Purchase-1',
    itemsizeId: '609578ca23033e55886e7590',
    itemId: '609578ca23033e55886e758e',
    sizeId: '60950c0ba4982390f8dfed79',
    movementdate: '2021-05-15T11:33:52.894Z',
    movementtype: 'inward',
    movementcategory: 'purchase',
    quantity: 100,
    id: '609fb1a1a7ed990f30d6cae2',
  },
  {
    _id: '609fb1cba7ed990f30d6cae3',
    refId: 'Purchase-2',
    itemsizeId: '609578ca23033e55886e7590',
    itemId: '609578ca23033e55886e758e',
    sizeId: '60950c0ba4982390f8dfed79',
    movementdate: '2021-05-15T11:34:35.118Z',
    movementtype: 'inward',
    movementcategory: 'purchase',
    quantity: 20,
    id: '609fb1cba7ed990f30d6cae3',
  },
  {
    _id: '609fb1fda7ed990f30d6cae4',
    refId: 'Sale-1',
    itemsizeId: '609578ca23033e55886e7590',
    itemId: '609578ca23033e55886e758e',
    sizeId: '60950c0ba4982390f8dfed79',
    movementdate: '2021-05-15T11:35:25.068Z',
    movementtype: 'outward',
    movementcategory: 'sales',
    quantity: 5,
    id: '609fb1fda7ed990f30d6cae4',
  },
  {
    _id: '609fb255a7ed990f30d6cae5',
    refId: 'Purchase-3',
    itemsizeId: '609578ca23033e55886e758f',
    itemId: '609578ca23033e55886e758e',
    sizeId: '60950be9a4982390f8dfed78',
    movementdate: '2021-05-15T11:36:53.835Z',
    movementtype: 'inward',
    movementcategory: 'purchase',
    quantity: 500,
    id: '609fb255a7ed990f30d6cae5',
  },
  {
    _id: '609fb27ea7ed990f30d6cae6',
    refId: 'Sale-2',
    itemsizeId: '609578ca23033e55886e758f',
    itemId: '609578ca23033e55886e758e',
    sizeId: '60950be9a4982390f8dfed78',
    movementdate: '2021-05-15T11:37:34.066Z',
    movementtype: 'outward',
    movementcategory: 'sales',
    quantity: 8,
    id: '609fb27ea7ed990f30d6cae6',
  },
]
```

I have tried till below code and I'm struck to complete it:

```
const itemStock = await itemStockMovementModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { movementtype: 'inward' },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        itemsizeId: '$itemsizeId',
      },
      quantity: { $sum: '$quantity' },
    },
  },
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `itemsizeId` and get quantity sum by condition for `inward` and `outward`
- `$subtract` to `inward` - `outward`

```
const itemStock = await itemStockMovementModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$itemsizeId",
      inward: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$movementtype", "inward"] }, "$quantity", 0] }
      },
      outward: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$movementtype", "outward"] }, "$quantity", 0] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      quantity: {
        $subtract: ["$inward", "$outward"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GLWrtLBvNHJ)

---

You can use second formula as well, if you don't have third type in `movementtype`,

- `$group` by `itemsizeId`
- check condition if `movementtype` is `inward` then sum `quantity` otherwise sum negative `quantity`

```
const itemStock = await itemStockMovementModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$itemsizeId",
      quantity: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$movementtype", "inward"] },
            "$quantity",
            { $subtract: [0, "$quantity"] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yU254I5R2r9)